# MBN00000002 [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] - authentication error to GMAIL via OAuth2

Tags: c#, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client, gmail-imap

I need to implement an IMAP or POP3 connection to GMAIL via my application written in C#.
For interfacing I use a DLL distributed by https://afterlogic.com/ - MailBee.Net Object DLL.

The connection using the DLL works correctly with Microsoft Exchange, but I cannot find a way to connect to GMAIL in the same way.

My application has no GUI, so it is critical that no iteration with the user is required.

To try connection to GMAIL I am referring to this documentation page, specifically the first of the two examples

https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/#OAuth2.html

Unfortunately I keep getting the same error when logging in to GMAIL.

[image]

The credentials of the Google application created on our console were configured by referring to the following official documentation
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

This is the code implemented in my application

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using Azure.Identity;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using MailBee;
using MailBee.ImapMail;
using MailBee.SmtpMail;
using Microsoft.Graph;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://mail.google.com/", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" };

        Console.WriteLine("Requesting authorization");
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "my client id",
                ClientSecret = "my client secret"

            },
             scopes,
             "user",
             CancellationToken.None).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Authorization granted or not required (if the saved access token already available)");

        if (credential.Token.IsExpired(credential.Flow.Clock))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The access token has expired, refreshing it");
            if (credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The access token is now refreshed");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The access token has expired but we can't refresh it :(");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The access token is OK, continue");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Requesting the e-mail address of the user from Google");

        Oauth2Service oauthService = new Oauth2Service(
            new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential });

        Console.WriteLine("E-mail address is " + "myemailaddr@gmail.com");

        string xoauthKey = OAuth2.GetXOAuthKeyStatic("myemailaddr@gmail.com", credential.Token.AccessToken);

        Imap imp = new Imap();

        imp.Log.Enabled = true;
        imp.Log.Filename = @"C:\APP_BCK\log.txt";
        imp.Log.HidePasswords = false;
        imp.Log.Clear();

        imp.Connect("imap.gmail.com");

        imp.Login(null, xoauthKey, AuthenticationMethods.SaslOAuth2,
            MailBee.AuthenticationOptions.None, null);
        
        imp.SelectFolder("INBOX");
        Console.WriteLine(imp.MessageCount.ToString() + " e-mails in Inbox");
        imp.Disconnect();


    }

}
```

Below are some print-screens of the application we created on our console, if they can be of any help

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this example I make the connection via the IMAP protocol, but I have tried with POP3 with the same result.

Does anyone have any idea how to properly make the connection?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is for an installed app and is going to require that the user authorization the application via a web browser window

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo, the browser, however, is only opened the first time my application runs. On subsequent runs it is no longer opened, probably until the token expires. For my application this might even be okay if the token had a long lifetime.
Otherwise, what might be an alternative to GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync that could be used in applications without iteration with the user?

Comment: That is because by default it uses filedatastore which is storing your token in %appdata% on your machine.   This token will only expire if your app is currently in testing, in which case the refresh token will expire in seven days.

Answer (score 0):

## Oauth2 option

GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is designed for use with installed application by default it uses FileDatastore which stores your user credetinals in %appData% see ([filedatastore demystified](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/))

If your application is still in testing phase then your refresh token will only last for seven days at which point you will need to authorize your application again, however to do that you must delete the file stored in %appData% or change "user" in your authorization to some other string to prompt it to request authorization again.

## Service account option

If you have a google workspace account you could use a service account. by configuring [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation)

## Apps Password

Or you could use an [apps password](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_u5KIeXiVI).  In place of your actual google password.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        {
            Port = 587,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(From , GoogleAppPassword),
            EnableSsl = true,
        };
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(From),
            Subject = Subject,
            Body = Body,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
        };
        mailMessage.To.Add(To);

        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  for the reply, I opted for a Google Workspace account subscription.
I configured the service accant granting access to https://mail.google.com/.

In this way, however, all users belonging to the domain of the service account can use this account to obtain an access token and read emails. Is it possible to limit access to this service account only to a specific domain user?

Comment: No its not, once a service account has been grated domain wide delegation it can impersonate any user on the domain.   There is no way to limit it.